# React animation inside If statement does not render

Tags: reactjs

I have a react animation component inside of an if block as follows;

```
import { CSSTransitionGroup } from 'react-transition-group'

......
......
......
......


render() {
   return(
      <div className="App"
         {
           this.state.isloading 
             ? <div className="loader"></div>
             : <CSSTransitionGroup
                 transitionName="example"
                 transitionEnterTimeout={1000}
                 transitionLeaveTimeout={750}
               >
                 {this.state.hot_list.length > 0 
                   ? <Displaycont hot_list={this.state.hot_list} /> 
                   : null}
              </CSSTransitionGroup>
          }
      </div>
 )
}
```

This does not render the animation only the component "Displaycont".

If I remove the If block the animation is rendered as expected. I am styling it as shown here;

https://reactjs.org/docs/animation.html#low-level-api-reacttransitiongroup

Any ideas what might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CSSTransitionGroup` should be always mounted and only its children have to be conditionally rendered.

I'm not sure of the reason, but all React documentation examples do it in that way. I guess, it's because of the `CSSTransitionGroup` lifecycle methods and the way they work.

**However, here's how you can do it**:

```
render () {
  const { isLoading, hot_list } = this.state

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      { isLoading ? <div className='loader' /> : null }
      <CSSTransitionGroup
        transitionName='example'
        transitionEnterTimeout={1000}
        transitionLeaveTimeout={750}
      >
        { isloading && hot_list.length > 0 ? <Displaycont hot_list={hot_list} /> : null }
      </CSSTransitionGroup>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank You! It seems to have solved the issue. The animation is being rendered after taking out the conditional rendering from the `CSSTransitionGroup` component.

Comment: You're welcome! If you're curious why this happen, you can take a look at [CSSTransitionGroup source code](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/tree/master/src). If the answer helped you, you can consider vote / accept it. Thank you!

Comment: I up-voted your answer, but I don't have enough reputation yet :( to be counted as a "real" vote :). I guess I will have to come back after I am old enough to make a real vote :)

Comment: It's because you had 14 reputation. 15 rep is needed for vote up privileges. Now, you have enough reputation for voting and accepting. All the best! :)